# Get the size of a conditional subset of a list

Tags: python, performance, list, subset

Assume that you have a list with an arbitrary amounts of items, and you wish to get the number of items that match a specific conditions. I though of two ways to do this in a sensible manner but I am not sure which one is best (more *pythonic*) - or if there is perhaps a better option (without sacrificing too much readability).

```
import numpy.random as nprnd
import timeit

my = nprnd.randint(1000, size=1000000)

def with_len(my_list):
    much = len([t for t in my_list if t >= 500])

def with_sum(my_list):
    many = sum(1 for t in my_list if t >= 500)

t1 = timeit.Timer('with_len(my)', 'from __main__ import with_len, my')
t2 = timeit.Timer('with_sum(my)', 'from __main__ import with_sum, my')

print("with len:",t1.timeit(1000)/1000)
print("with sum:",t2.timeit(1000)/1000)
```

Performance is almost identical between these two cases. However, which of these is more *pythonic*? Or is there a better alternative?

---

For those who are curious, I tested the proposed solutions (from comments and answers) and these are the results:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import functools

my = np.random.randint(1000, size=100000)

def with_len(my_list):
    return len([t for t in my_list if t >= 500])

def with_sum(my_list):
    return sum(1 for t in my_list if t >= 500)

def with_sum_alt(my_list):
    return sum(t >= 500 for t in my_list)

def with_lambda(my_list):
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + (1 if b >= 500 else 0), my_list, 0)

def with_np(my_list):
    return len(np.where(my_list>=500)[0])

t1 = timeit.Timer('with_len(my)', 'from __main__ import with_len, my')
t2 = timeit.Timer('with_sum(my)', 'from __main__ import with_sum, my')
t3 = timeit.Timer('with_sum_alt(my)', 'from __main__ import with_sum_alt, my')
t4 = timeit.Timer('with_lambda(my)', 'from __main__ import with_lambda, my')
t5 = timeit.Timer('with_np(my)', 'from __main__ import with_np, my')

print("with len:", t1.timeit(1000)/1000)
print("with sum:", t2.timeit(1000)/1000)
print("with sum_alt:", t3.timeit(1000)/1000)
print("with lambda:", t4.timeit(1000)/1000)
print("with np:", t5.timeit(1000)/1000)
```

Python 2.7

```
('with len:', 0.02201753337348283)
('with sum:', 0.022727363518455238)
('with sum_alt:', 0.2370256687439941) # <-- very slow!
('with lambda:', 0.026367264818657078)
('with np:', 0.0005811764306089913) # <-- very fast!
```

Python 3.6

```
with len: 0.017649643657480736
with sum: 0.0182978007766851
with sum_alt: 0.19659815740239048
with lambda: 0.02691670741400111
with np: 0.000534095418615152
```

Comment: Consider alternatively `sum(t>=500 for t in my_list)`

Comment: @khelwood I guess that'd work as well, but I'm not sure if that'd make a difference with `with_sum`.

Comment: If you feel functional today: `reduce(lambda a, b: a + (1 if b >= 500 else 0), my_list, 0)`

Comment: @khelwood Interestingly enough, your suggestion is ten times slower than the original suggestion.

Comment: @BramVanroy That _is_ interesting.

Comment: @BramVanroy Also interesting is that the performance difference between approaches is noticeably different in Python 2.7 -- the (non-numpy) results are all closer together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with @Chris_Rands. But as far as performance is concerned, there is a faster way using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def with_np(my_list):
    return len(np.where(my_list>=500)[0])
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredibly fast. Any clue as to why this is so fast? (~50 times faster than my original approach)

Comment: @BramVanroy yes. Though numpy arrays, or, ndarrays to be more specific, are similar in terms of structure to native lists, they are very different under the hood. By design they are meant to deal with multi-dimensional matrices and linear algebra by combining the simplicity and idiomatic nature of python and low-level language performance, allowing easy vectorization and complex operations at low cost. Essentially ndarrays are stride views on memory.

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd one, `with_sum` is more pythonic in the sense that it uses much less memory as it doesn't build the whole list because the generator expression is fed to `sum()`.

Comment: Though the first one can do the very same thing by simply removing the `[` `]`.

Comment: @AdamBarnes No, you can't use `len()` on a generator, try it